Powershell : Cannot convert the "java" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"
I have a powershell script which converts the String and String[] into a BlockScript. It was working until now but it starts to fail suddenly after some windows upgrade.
function Invoke-ForegroundCommand {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [scriptblock]
        $Command
    )

    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Command -Verbose
    $exitCode = $LASTEXITCODE
}


$javaOptions = @()
$javaOptions + @(
        "-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
        "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
        "-XX:+UseG1GC"
        "-Xms512m"
        "-Xmx2048m"
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED"
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED"
    )

Invoke-ForegroundCommand -Command "java" -Arguments $javaOpts


It throws the exception "Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Command'. Cannot convert the "java" value of type
| "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"."
I have already tried to wrap "java" and $javaOptions into a command block using {} and also tried to create a script block using
$command = "java $javaOptions" 
or $command = "java " + ($javaOptions -join " ")

$ScriptBlock = [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create($command)

I could not get it working. Do you know how to get it working?

invoke-command localhost { java $using:javaoptions; $LASTEXITCODE } (assuming $javaoptions is set correctly)

Your invocation attempt (Invoke-ForegroundCommand -Command "java" -Arguments $javaOptions) cannot work, in any PowerShell version, for two reasons:

A string cannot automatically be converted to a [scriptblock].

The simplest way to verify this is with a direct cast, which applies the same conversion rules as parameter declarations: [scriptblock] 'java' predictably fails, with the same (core) error message as in your question.

Converting a string containing a piece of source code to a script block requires calling a method, namely [scriptblock]::Create().



Because your function is an advanced one (due to use of a [Parameter()] attribute), only explicitly declared parameters may be bound; so your -ArgumentList argument would be rejected (this error would only surface once you pass an actual script block to the -Command parameter).


To make your java call work with your existing function, enclose the whole java command - including its arguments - in a script block literal ({ ... }):
Invoke-ForegroundCommand -Command { java @javaOptions }

Note:

For conceptual clarity, splatting is used to pass the elements of array $javaOptions as individual arguments, which is achieved by using @ instead of $; that said, since java is an external program, this isn't strictly necessary, as splatting happens implicitly in that case.

At least as shown, your function provides no added functionality beyond directly invoking a command; that is, just java @javaOptions should do.

There is no point in using [scriptblock]::Create() in this scenario, since you know the program to execute as well as the arguments to pass to it, which makes of a script block literal (enclosure in { ... }) the simplest solution; if you do want to use the method nonetheless, as you attempted in your question, you'd have to do this:
$ScriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create('java @javaOptions')


Note the use of a verbatim string ('...') and the reference to the $javaOptions variable (via splatting) that exists in the current scope - no need for string interpolation, which would prove challenging with array elements containing spaces, for instance.



